# Curva Quadrática Estimação Minimos Quadrado usando R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Eu tenho um modelo quadrático que eu quero rodar uma simples regressão multivariada usando Minimos Quadrados Ordinarios.

Esse é o meu codigo:

```
df<-data.frame(rnorm(50),rnorm(50))
x_Square<-df[,2]^2
data<-cbind(df,x_Square)
names(data)<-c("y","x","x_Square")
regression<-lm(data$y ~ data$x + data$x_Square)
```

Agora eu quero plotar o gráfico da curva quadrática ajustada no gráfico de dispersão (y - x).

Como faço isso?

Quando faço: `plot(regression)` não tenho essa opção.

Alguma ajuda?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que os teus dados não possuem estrutura de regressão quadrática. Eu criaria um outro conjunto de dados da seguinte forma:

```
set.seed(321)

n     <- 20 # numero de observacoes
x1    <- rep(1:n/2, each=2) # variavel deterministica linear
x2    <- x1^2 # variavel deterministica quadratica
y     <- -10*x1 + x2 + rnorm(n) # criacao do y, juntando x1, x2 e um erro
dados <- data.frame(y, x1, x2) # banco de dados final
```

Com a criação do banco de dados, podemos proceder com o ajuste de um modelo 
a eles, bem como a plotagem dos resultados:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dados, aes(x=x1+x2, y=y)) + geom_point()

ajuste <- lm(y ~ x1+x2)
summary(ajuste)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.4894 -0.6994  0.2779  0.6104  2.5972 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.09502    0.62532   0.152     0.88    
x1          -10.05787    0.27428 -36.670   <2e-16 ***
x2            1.00529    0.02537  39.619   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.189 on 37 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9778,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9766 
F-statistic:   814 on 2 and 37 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Note como as estimativas de `x1` e `x2` batem com os coeficientes definidos na criação da variável `y`.

A seguir eu crio um data frame novo, só para plotar os resultados da regressão. Eu poderia ter utilizado `geom_smooth()`, mas acho que desta forma fica mais didático.

```
regressao <- data.frame(x1, ajuste$fitted.values)
names(regressao) <- c("x1", "fitted")

ggplot(dados, aes(x=x1, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
geom_line(data=regressao, aes(x=x1, y=fitted, colour="red"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeu Marcus! Eu queria entortar a curva mesmo sem y seguir uma especificação quadrática. Mas me ajudou bastante! Obrigado.

Comment: @DiogoBastos Se a resposta do Marcus resolveu o seu problema, não se esqueça de escolhe-la como a melhor resposta!

Comment: Ok @Molx, feito!